# MOXy shows error 'multiple mappable parent interfaces' on transient members/properties

Tags: xml, jaxb, mapping, moxy, oxm

I'm using external mapping files to define the marshalling of my objects. My test app (link@bottom) has this [class_model.png](http://kinetiek.com/files/moxy/classmodel.png): 3 classes **Contact**, **Relation** and **Country** who all implements their own interface *IContact*, *IRelation* and *ICountry*. These 3 interfaces extends multiple super-interfaces. The 3 classes are related: class **Contact** has a *IRelation* member, and class **Relation** has a *ICountry* member.

To avoid the error '*The java interface can not be mapped by JAXB as it has multiple mappable parent interfaces*' I super-type the 3 interfaces to java.lang.Object in my mapping file, as described by Blaise Doughan on his blog.

I would like to hide the marshalling of the **Country** in class **Relation**, so I add a *xml-transient* element for the country member in **Relation**.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/eclipselink_oxm_2_4.xsd"
package-name="com.foo.domain"
xml-mapping-metadata-complete="false" xml-accessor-type="PROPERTY">
<xml-schema element-form-default="QUALIFIED" />
<java-types>
    <java-type name="Contact">
        <xml-root-element />
        <java-attributes>
            <xml-element java-attribute="relation"
                type="com.foo.domain.Relation" />
        </java-attributes>
    </java-type>
    <java-type name="Relation">
        <xml-root-element />
        <java-attributes>
            <xml-transient java-attribute="country" />
        </java-attributes>
    </java-type>
    <!-- ###### I want to delete this line ###### -->
    <!-- <java-type name="ICountry" super-type="java.lang.Object" /> -->
    <java-type name="IRelation" super-type="java.lang.Object" />
    <java-type name="IContact" super-type="java.lang.Object" />
</java-types>
```

The country is not marshalled, thanks to the *xml-transient*. So i guess MOXy doesn't process the **Country**, so I don't need the super-type the *ICountry* anymore. When I remove the *ICountry* *super-type* from the mapping, I get the error 'The java interface ICountry can not be mapped by JAXB as it has multiple mappable parent interfaces.' again during the process of creating a JAXBContext.

Why do I get this error while the **Country** object is not being processed by MOXy beacuse of the *xml-transient*?

I have a large domain model/object tree (300 domains, 80 packages) where every domain implement an interface with multiple super-interfaces. I espected that I could marshall a subset of the object tree by using the *xml-transient* element. But it seems that MOXy needs a *super-type* for every interface in the object tree, even if the interface is implemented by classes who are not getting marshalled. Because the OXM-mappings are package-based, it implies that I have to include 80 mapping files for all the interfaces to create a valid JAXBContext.

How should my mapping file be defined so MOXy does not inspects any interfaces/classes that are excluded from the marshalling process? How can i marshall a subset of a huge object tree whitout the need of every interfcae being super-typed?

Any help is very appreciated.

**Links with more info:**
Link to the [test_app.zip](http://kinetiek.com/files/moxy/test_app.zip) which demonstrates the behaviour in several unittests with different mapping files.